# Google Endpoint in front of GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, google-cloud-endpoints

I cannot seem to find any reference materials for setting up a Google Endpoint API Gateway in front of a GraphQL API.

Any help or leads to reference material would be great.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: could you explain a little bit more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am setting up a GraphQL API in GCP App Engine as well as several other future services and I want all traffic to come through an API Gateway that provides me enhanced security, monitoring, and reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this setup and it works. Supposing you have an `api.test.com/graphql` endpoint, you need to define a path the usual way in your yaml config file:

```
paths:
  /graphql:
    post:
      description: "graphql http-post endpoint"
      operationId: "graphql-post"
      produces:
        - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Echo"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/echo_message"
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this works?  Not suggesting that it doesn't but I currently don't have enough knowledge to decide if it does or not.